# Is it possible to pass data into annotations in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I would like to pass data into annotations in Google Analytics. Is it currenty possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but the only thing that you can put into annotations are text strings via the interface (i.e. you cannot create annotations programmatically via the management API). So the answer is probably "no".